# Excel VBA - how to account for errors from searching

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sheets("Table").Select
Cells.Find(What:="Cat", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 1).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=-1).Select
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 10).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Table").Select
Cells.Find(What:="Bat", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 1).Activate
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=-1).Select
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 10).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

I'm very new to excel and trying to account for errors that will occur when one of the words I'm searching for are not on the table. I'm not sure how to format it to work, but basically for the first search, if it errors then go to the next search without doing any of selection, copy, and paste part (same for the second search).

Comment: After completing the search, check the variable that contains the results to see if it equals Nothing. This will tell you if the search found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Range` variable to assign your find function to, then use an `If` statement to determine if it exists or not.  If no, move to the next one.

```
Dim fRange As Range

Sheets("Table").Select
Set fRange = Cells.Find(What:="Cat", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 1)

If Not fRange Is Nothing Then

fRange.Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=-1).Select
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 10).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End If


Sheets("Table").Select
Set fRange = Cells.Find(What:="Bat", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 1)

If Not fRange Is Nothing Then

fRange.Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=-1).Select
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 0, Selection.Columns.Count + 10).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End If
```